# Opendir with php fails

Tags: php, opendir

Php version: *PHP Version 7.4.13*

by using opendir() with the following code:

$dir     = "Z:\Chemie\DMCODEJS\Titrationen\TiamoExportDateien/";

```
    Print_r("<hr>");
    Print_r("Dir: " . $dir);
    Print_r("<hr>");
    
    $handle  = opendir($dir);
    
    Print_r("<hr>");
    Print_r("Ende");
    Print_r("<hr>");
```

and we get the following error-message:

```
*Dateiliste: Dir: Z:\Chemie\DMCODEJS\Titrationen\TiamoExportDateien/
```

Warning: opendir(Z:\Chemie\DMCODEJS\Titrationen\TiamoExportDateien/,Z:\Chemie\DMCODEJS\Titrationen\TiamoExportDateien/): Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden. (code: 3) in E:\lafuwa-xampp\htdocs\TIAA\php\classes\ClsAjAuswertung.php on line 128
Warning: opendir(Z:\Chemie\DMCODEJS\Titrationen\TiamoExportDateien/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in E:\lafuwa-xampp\htdocs\TIAA\php\classes\ClsAjAuswertung.php on line 128
Ende*

Comment: Are the script and directory on the same computer? Has the php (process) user permissions to access the directory? Additionally you should escape the `\\` in PHP strings.

Comment: Is there any good reason that your string mixes forward and backward slashes?